# Firebase login promise doesn't resolve until I tap anywhere on the screen

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm following this [React course on Udemy](https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReactNativeReduxCasts) and I've come across a really strange error.

I'm using Firebase to authenticate via email and password. When users tap log in, I dispatch an action called LOGIN_USER, which sets a loading state.

When login is successful, I dispatch an action called `LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS` to stop the loading state.

For some reason, `LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS` doesn't happen until I tap somewhere random on the screen.

If I remove the line `dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });` to disable the loading state, login returns success after a couple of seconds.

```
My actions
-----------

export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);

        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
          .catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch));
      });
  };
};

const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    payload: user
  });
};


const INITIAL_STATE = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
  user: null,
  error: '',
  loading: false
};


/// My reducer
---------------

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMAIL_CHANGED:
      return { ...state, email: action.payload };
    case PASSWORD_CHANGED:
      return { ...state, password: action.payload };
    case LOGIN_USER:
      return { ...state, loading: true, error: '' };
    case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, ...INITIAL_STATE, user: action.payload };
    case LOGIN_USER_FAIL:
      return { ...state, error: 'Authentication Failed.', password: '', loading: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I tried `.then(user => console.log(user))` and I don't see the console log until after I tap randomly anywhere on the screen.

If I do `.then(console.log('foo')` I see foo immediately, but the screen still hangs.

As I mentioned, I'm following a tutorial and the full source is [here on GitHub](https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReactNativeReduxCasts/tree/135-showing-a-spinner/manager/src). I've basically got exactly the same code.

Comment: I'm following one of his Udemy courses as well, and ran into the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I just ignored the problem as it seems to be a simulator issue. That said, with an updated version of Xcode, I built my project from within Xcode (rather than react-native run-ios in the command line) and it opened a different simulator which didn’t have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. It seems that some firebase functions doesn't work properly in simulator or emulator. I tried running my application in iphone device and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to sign in users in firebase is to register a callback to `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(call_back)`
. You can dispatch your action from this callback